# how to download and save exchange data every 5 minutes using python

Tags: python, trading

I have recently started out on python and learnt all the basic courses. I don't know how I would download and save price/volume information every 5 minutes during the trading day using python/excel.

I have developed a connection from my excel spreadsheet to the exchange which shows me live price/volumes for the product.

Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. This is too broad. We're not here to provide tutorials or to write code for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `threading`'s `Timer` class.
An example:

```py
import threading

def print_hello_world():
    threading.Timer(1, print_hello_world).start()
    print('Hello World')

print_hello_world()
```

This prints the hello world every 1 second (for 5 minutes, think what you should be changing; also think what you should be changing the `print_hello_world()` method to to fit your use case).

This is a very basic snippet. Obviously you can build on it by adding stop methods and so on. But I would suggest using Google to search your query first, as you should have in yourself to find solutions to simple problems on your own. Nonetheless, good luck on your journey with Python.